# How can I completely remove the Margin of textboxes in HTML/css

Tags: html, css, textbox, margins

I have the following HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .box
    {
        border:solid black 1px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input class="box" style="width:300px;" /><br />
        <input class="box" style="width:150px;" />
        <input class="box" style="width:150px;" /><br />
        <input class="box" style="width:100px;" />
        <input class="box" style="width:100px;" />
        <input class="box" style="width:100px;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that the textboxes should finish pixel perfect on the right hand side.

I will eventually add spacing on rows 2 and 3 enlarging the widths to compensate, but for the moment I would like to get this simple sample to render.

So **how can I remove the margins of these textboxes such that the align properly?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not lining up because of the whitespace between them.

If you were to remove all the newlines and tabs between the `<input>` elements, it would display as you want.

Comment: I forgot about this annoying thing. Removing this will work also.

Comment: Works as well as Ross' answer and does not require Float ( which suits me better) but still suffers from strange total widths? See comment made under his answer.

Comment: To keep things clearer, I'm going to ask about the "total widths strangeness" as a separate question

Comment: This has bitten me multiple times. Always forget about the whitespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found adding `float: left;` to .box did what you wanted.

```
.box {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This kinda works. However there seems to be a discrepancy in the total widths. I have to remove 2 pixels from the first text box on row 2 and the first 2 on the 3rd row in order to line everything up... This seems wrong

Comment: True - I've just realised RoBorg's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413573/how-can-i-completely-remove-the-margin-of-textboxes-in-html-css#413608) is more correct, mine just does the same thing a little wrongly.

Comment: by the way it looks very different on chrome and IE.

Comment: To keep things clearer, I'm going to ask about the "total widths strangeness" as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about right justifying all the textboxes?

If so, that's not a margin question.  That's simply putting the textboxes in a containing element.  Perhaps a  and then set the text-align: right; css style on the div.

Answer (score 0):

The border is not included in the width, so a box with a 1px border and a width of 150px will actually be 152 px wide.